# What causes NullPointerException in android?

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I am newbie to android game development. I've been trying an example of game development but some how unable to understand the cause of null point exception in android.

```
    public void onLoadResources() {
         this.mBitmapTextureAtlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(512, 512,
               TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);
        BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.setAssetBasePath("gfx/");

        this.mPlayerTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory
                .createFromAsset(this.mBitmapTextureAtlas, this, "Player.png",
                0, 0);
        this.mEngine.getTextureManager().loadTexture(this.mBitmapTextureAtlas);
        final int PlayerX = (int)(mCamera.getWidth() / 2);
        final int PlayerY = (int) ((mCamera.getHeight() - mPlayerTextureRegion
                .getHeight()) / 2);
        this.player = new Sprite(PlayerX, PlayerY, this.mPlayerTextureRegion);
        this.player.setScale(2);
        this.mMainScene.attachChild(this.player);
    }
```

The last line `"this.mMainScene.attachChild(this.player);"` is causing null point exception, even though everything is intialized. After commenting this line everything works fine but display is without sprite.

here is the code where mMainScene is intialized

```
    public Scene onLoadScene() {
        this.mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new FPSLogger());
        this.mMainScene = new Scene();
        this.mMainScene.setBackground(new ColorBackground(0.09804f, 0.6274f, 0.8784f));
        return mMainScene;
    }
```

Comment: The cause is not different from Java, by the way. See also the API docs: [java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) versus [android](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/NullPointerException.html).

Comment: Could you post the code where you initialize `mMainScene`?

Comment: well i edited the question as you asked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have not initialized mMainScene. You cannot reference (i.e. attach Children / call methods until you've defined what mMainScene is.)

Could you check if mMainScene is null, or move your assignment of mMainScene into onLoadResources()?

Can you move the mMainScene definition from onLoadScene into onLoadResources?

```
public void onLoadResources() {
     this.mBitmapTextureAtlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(512, 512,
           TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);
    BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.setAssetBasePath("gfx/");

    this.mPlayerTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory
            .createFromAsset(this.mBitmapTextureAtlas, this, "Player.png",
            0, 0);
    this.mEngine.getTextureManager().loadTexture(this.mBitmapTextureAtlas);
    final int PlayerX = (int)(mCamera.getWidth() / 2);
    final int PlayerY = (int) ((mCamera.getHeight() - mPlayerTextureRegion
            .getHeight()) / 2);
    this.player = new Sprite(PlayerX, PlayerY, this.mPlayerTextureRegion);
    this.player.setScale(2);
    this.mMainScene = new Scene();
    this.mMainScene.setBackground(new ColorBackground(0.09804f, 0.6274f, 0.8784f));
    this.mMainScene.attachChild(this.player);
}

public Scene onLoadScene() {
    return mMainScene;
}
```

Edit:

Based on an example of [Snake](https://code.google.com/p/andengineexamples/source/browse/src/org/anddev/andengine/examples/game/snake/SnakeGameActivity.java) it appears that you should add children to the scene in the onLoadScene method:

```
    public Scene onLoadScene() {
        this.mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new FPSLogger());

        this.mScene = new Scene();
        for(int i = 0; i < LAYER_COUNT; i++) {
            this.mScene.attachChild(new Entity());
    }
```

Comment: mMainScene is initialized by onLoadScene() in same class, the class extends BaseGameActivity of andengine.

Comment: There should be documentation about the order of execution of these methods?

Comment: nope can not because , onLoadScene may be called from outside, although i changed it by

Comment: nope can not because , onLoadScene may be called from outside, although i changed it by mMainScene=onLoadScene(); but that removed the null point exception but my sprite is abscent!!

Comment: Take a look at this example for [Snake](https://code.google.com/p/andengineexamples/source/browse/src/org/anddev/andengine/examples/game/snake/SnakeGameActivity.java) -- It adds the sprites / scene children in onLoadScene (lines 160, 165) rather than onLoadResource like you've shown. I'll update my response above also.